# How to place flutter BottomNavigationBar in left side in landscape mode?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-layout, flutter-bottomnavigation

Expected View:

[image: expected view]

I need to place flutter BottomNavigationBar in left side of the screen in landscape mode. If this is impossible to do, please mention another alternative way if you know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

you can use a combination of BottomNavigationBar (portrait) and NavigationRail (landscape)

[navigationrail](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/navigationrail-widget-in-flutter-e041dc12c89c)

and for rotating widget in NavigationRail, use RotateBox

```
RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: -1,
```